probability problem with birthday
) I have again a problem with solution and I'm not sure, that I'm right. Can somebody check it?
Problem:
You are looking at 5 people who were born independently of each other.
a) What is the probability, that exactly two of these five people are born on the same day of week?
b) What is the probability, that at least two of these five people are born on the same day of week?
My solution:
a)$\mathbb{P}(\text{exactly 2 of 5 people)}=\frac{{5 \choose 2} \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4}{7^5}$
b)$\mathbb{P}(\text{at least 2 of 5 people})=1-\mathbb{P}(\text{no one is born at same day of week)}=1-\frac{7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3}{7^5}$.
Is it right?

How are you going to count the case of 2 on Monday, 2 on Wednesday and 1 on Friday?  Or 2 on Monday and 3 on Wednesday?

@Henry I dont need it for this problem. But with the same way with binom, isn't it?

@Henry like this  $\frac{{5 \choose 2} \cdot 7 \cdot {5 \choose 2} \cdot 6 \cdot 5}{7^5}$

My question was whether in your problem either "2 on Monday, 2 on Wednesday and 1 on Friday" or "2 on Monday and 3 on Wednesday" are examples of "exactly two of these five people are born on the same day of week"

@Henry ah. ok. no.

(a) Not exactly: the two people born on the same day have 7 weekdays to choose from; the next (3rd) person has 6 days to chose from, the 4th has 5 days and the 5th has 4 days, so the answer is $\frac{\binom{5}{2}\cdot 7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4}{7^5}=\frac{1200}{2401}$.
(b) Correct.
